# How to get the best match without looping through the entire database?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have a function that returns a compatibility percentage between 2 users.

```
    function get_compatibility(user1, user2) {
      ...
      return compatibility;
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to find the top 10 highest compatibility matches of a given user without having to loop through the entire database. Is that even possible?

Looping through the database wouldn't be a problem if the number of users was small. But if let's say the database grew to a hundred thousand users, then I'd have to calculate the compatibility% about a hundred thousand times and order the results. Obviously, this is not scalable.

Comment: You can use a LIMIT clause in your query, that will give you the number of records that you need, and you won't have to loop through the records in your code.

Comment: It has to be a O(N^2) if you're going to check all users against each other. I'd do it periodically, store the results, and index them for fast ordering.

Comment: The complexity of a solution for your problem is highly influenced by what being compatible means. For instance, if compatibility means being around the same age, then you can simply order the users based on date of birth, once for all the users (perhaps by keeping an index on date_of_birth column) and then you can easily pick closest 10 users to any user that requires that...

Comment: ...However, compatibility might mean something a lot more complex, perhaps depending on a lot of columns. Compatibility might be some sort of a distance in between some multi-dimensional vectors that describe your users. This would make exact solutions expensive to obtain. But you can go for a heuristic approach. Finding a good such solution highly depends on what compatibility means.

Comment: I was thinking about doing it like duffymo said, but the problem would be scalability. If the DB grew to 1 million users, there would be 1 trillion rows for compatibility% if you count all permutations. Obviously, that's too big.

Comment: Yea, the function to get the compatibility would be relatively complex which is why I didn't include it. It's simple to calculate for just 2 users, but if I were to calculate it for each permutations, that would get expensive fast. I'm going to have to look into a heuristic approach, even if the results are not exact.

Answer (score 2):

Just as cobarzan said, it all depends on what you mean by "compatibility".

Supposing that we're talking about attributes and how close they are to each other, your best bet is probably to use something similar to [MinHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash) to build a lookup table the first time, where you precalculate an index for every user giving them an hash (see above ) in reference to an "universal" set with all the values to the max and then sorting by that.

Then, every time you add a user, you check where that user goes in the compatibility lookup and put it in the correct "similar" list.

For example, let's say that you have age and shoe size as compatibility parameters. Let's also say that the max value of age is 99 and the max value of shoe size is also 99.

Then you decide what your hash function is. This is just an example so to make it simple, let's say the hashing is (age+shoe_size)/age/99.

A user with an age of 27 and shoe size of 43 will have an index of (27+43)/27/99=0.0261 . A user with an age of 80 and shoe size of 40 will have an index of (80+40)/80/99=0.0151 .

The first time, you'll have to do this for every user and sort by that index.
Then every time you add a new user or one of the values in a user changes, you just have to put it in the right position, which is easy, because the list is already sorted.

Again, this is just guesswork because you didn't explain what "compatibility" is.